# Switching between external power and batteries with varying voltages

Tags: lipo, schottky

I want to supply some voltage regulators (12V, 5V and 3.3V) with one of two power sources: one wall power-supply and/or a LiPo-pack. The input voltage would be in the range of 10V-24V and a continous power draw of ~50W is expected. It should be always powered by either the external power-supply or the batteries.

If one of those power-sources fails (due to unplugging, etc.) it needs to switch to the other one.

Some problems I can think of are:

1. Schottky-diodes generate too much heat with my power requirements and I don't want to rely on active cooling.
2. Are there special requirements for the circuitry (e.g. can I build it on a protoboard w/o problems)?

How would best go about this given these requirements?

Comment: http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "ideal diode", such as the LTC4412, may be what you are looking for. They use FETs for switching so can handle plenty of current without too much heat.